# The Swiper Slider doesn't update the slide active state while playing the slider

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

For some reason, I have to use Swiper Slider V4.5.3. I set up a carousel and the content slider, but when clicking the carousel slide item, it should change the active state of the current item, but it doesn't. The active state is always stopped at the first item.

I tried many ways to fix it, but no luck. Even add slideChange event to output the activeIndex value, it always shows 0.

Hope anyone can give me the right direction. Thanks!

```js
var Nav = new Swiper('#nav', {
  spaceBetween: 0,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true
});

var NavContent = new Swiper('#content', {
  spaceBetween: 20,
  thumbs: {
    swiper: Nav
  }
});
```

```css
.swiper-slide-active {
  color: #f00;
}

.swiper-slide {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://nybilu.com/sources/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://nybilu.com/sources/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="nav" class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
     <div class="swiper-slide">Nav 1</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">Nav 2</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">Nav 3</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">Nav 4</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">Nav 5</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="content" class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
     <div class="swiper-slide">Content 1</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">content 2</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">content 3</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">content 4</div>
     <div class="swiper-slide">content 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the scripts after the content?
also, any errors in the console?

Comment: Yes, I have tried to move the script below the content, same result. And no error in the console.

Comment: how easy would be for you to replicate it on a codepen<https://codepen.io/> for us to see?